# Wirecloud workspace share

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

How can I share a Wirecloud workspace composition?

I have already shared a public composition, but It's possible to share a composition with selected users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible to share a workspace with a set of selected users. You can only choose between make the workspace private or make it public. Anyway, this feature is planned to be developed this summer, stay tuned.